# How reduce() higher order function works?

Tags: javascript

Below is `reduce()` function

```
function reduce(array, combine, start) { 
    let current = start;
    for (let element of array) { 
        current = combine(current, element); 
    }
    return current;
}
```

Now this is the question which i am solving

Use the reduce method in combination with the concat method to “flatten” an array of arrays into a single array that has all the elements of the original arrays.

Here is the solution

```
let arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4,5], [6]]; 
console.log(arrays.reduce((flat,current)=> flat.concat(current), []));
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Now if i try this

```
let arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, [79],5], [6]];
console.log(arrays.reduce((flat, current) => flat.concat(current), []));
```

I get this

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, [79], 5, 6]
```

It means that  this solution can get a flatten array only up to two nested array 
But how it works for this 
arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4,5], [6]];

Because in reduce() function i am using 
for( let elements of array) which by the way if i use

It works like this

```
array = [1,4,6,[6,7],7,6,8,6];
for(element of array) 
   console.log(element);

// 146[6,7]7686
```

It does not gets the value from nested array
Then how does it for the first solution
And how to write solution which works for any number of nested array i know it will use recursion but how ?

Comment: Your question isn’t very clear. You already correctly understood that this reducer can only flatten arrays one level deep. That’s why the first sample has no nested arrays, but the second one still has one. What are you not understanding now? Try going through the function line by line.

Comment: I want to know why this function can only flatten array up to one level deep ? And how to write a function which works for any number of nested array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**why this function can only flatten array up to one level deep ?**

```
let arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, [79],5], [6]];console.log(arrays.reduce((flat, current) => flat.concat(current), []))
```

Because the reduce function doesn't know if you are trying to concatenate a primitive (a number) or an array.  When the reduce functions tries to concatenate two arrays, it produces a single array, but it doesn't know if every element in the array is a number or an array.

Then, as you suggested, you can use **recursion**:

```
 function flatten(arrayToFlatten){
      return arrayToFlatten.reduce((prev, next)=>{
        if(!Array.isArray(next)){ // Base case, when you have a number
           return prev.concat(next);
        } else { // Recursive case, when you have an array
           return prev.concat(flatten(next));
        }
      }, []);
    }
```

Comment: @AtulMishra, if the answer satisfies you, would you mind to mark as answered?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```js
const arrays = [[1, 2, 3],[4, [79], 5],[6]];
const getFlatten = array => array.reduce((a, c) => a.concat(Array.isArray(c) ? getFlatten(c) : c), []);
const result = getFlatten(arrays);

console.log(result);
```